# Pan gesture behaving weird after default rotation and scale

Tags: ios, rotation, scale, pan

I am currently designing a little game as a learning project and it is basically the following, a image is rotated and scaled on `viewDidLoad` and another image is a direct copy of the original image.

So basically there is a image that is a little bit different from the other, the objective is to scale it back down, rotate it and move it on top of the other image with 5 pixels, 5 degrees of rotate and 5 percent scale.

I have run into an issue. I "skew" the image using the following code...

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.5);
image.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.25, 1.25);
```

My pan gesture does not perform correctly after rotating the image and then scaling it 125%.

Does anyone know what could be going on here? By incorrectly I mean that it doesn't move around with my finger.. It seems to glide or go the opposite direction. [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-ShzDP_wy4&feature=youtu.be) .

My pan gesture method is below.

```
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:image];
        //if within game field
        if((image.center.x + translation.x) > 50.0 && (image.center.x + translation.x) < 255.0 && (image.center.y + translation.y) > 50.0 && (image.center.y + translation.y) < 302) {
            [image setCenter:CGPointMake([image center].x + translation.x, [image center].y + translation.y)]; //move it
        }
    }
    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[image superview]];
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) [self didWin]; // not relevant to question
```

Does anyone know why pan performs incorrectly after I rotate and scale my image? When I comment out those first two lines of code the pan performs correctly and moves around with the users finger.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the pan code just a tiny bit..

```
if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [gesture translationInView:self.view]; //CHANGED
        //if within game field
        if((image.center.x + translation.x) > 50.0 && (image.center.x + translation.x) < 255.0 && (image.center.y + translation.y) > 50.0 && (image.center.y + translation.y) < 302) {
            [image setCenter:CGPointMake([image center].x + translation.x, [image center].y + translation.y)]; //move it
        }
    }
    [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
```

I *changed* `in view:self.view` and `translationInView:self.view];`

Answer (score 1):

Rotation might have changed the frame. I used **cosf** and **sinf** function to deal with it.

handlePan and handleRotate are the callback functions, in which I can control the subview of self.view. Here, you should replace **image** with your own view.

```
static CGFloat _rotation = 0;

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    UIImageView *image = nil;
    for (UIImageView *tmp in recognizer.view.subviews) { // pick the subview
        if (tmp.tag == AXIS_TAG) {
            image = tmp;
        }
    }
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:image];

    // I have found any related documents yet, but these equations do work!//////
    CGFloat dx = translation.x * cosf(_rotation) - translation.y*sinf(_rotation);
    CGFloat dy = translation.x * sinf(_rotation) + translation.y*cosf(_rotation);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x+dx, dy+image.center.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:image];
}

- (void)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    UIImageView *image = nil;
    for (UIImageView *tmp in recognizer.view.subviews) { // pick the subview
        if (tmp.tag == AXIS_TAG) {
            image = tmp;
        }
    }
    CGFloat r = [recognizer rotation];
    if ((recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
        && recognizer.numberOfTouches == 2) {
        image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(_rotation+r);
    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        _rotation+=r; // Record the final rotation
    }
}
```